# How can a ESP8266 GPIO pin voltage be higher than source voltage?

Tags: esp8266, pullup

[image: SChematic]

I have a project that uses an esp8266 12F module and have recently had 2 boards fail on the same pin. It is GPIO12 and is being used as an input with the internal pull-up enabled. The pin is connected to a float switch that can be in the on/off position for long periods. I noticed when trying to troubleshoot this issue and by testing other boards i have, that when the pins are set to pull-up enabled the voltage goes to a higher level than the supply voltage. The difference ranges from +.04V to 0.39V+!! Which is above the rated voltage for this mcu's pins.

This makes my brain hurt. I know you can boost voltage but generally this is done with a high frequency switch and analogue components. I wouldn't expect this effect to be accidentally replicated either.

My project does use interrupts on one of the other pull-up pins, if this somehow has some influence.

I have noticed this higher voltage on the other two pins I have running pull-ups as well. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

---

Update from comments on a now-deleted answer:

The regulator I use is the AZ1117CD and is rated for a max of 18V input. Apologies for misleading [with the wrong part number AP1084D33L on the schematic]. I just used the footprint from a previous design and missed the name change on that. Although I agree that the inductive loads could have an issue I do have external protection on both of those loads and I don't think the blown pins could have been caused by this [...]. However, the increased voltage is noted on raw new esp8266 12F modules I have before connecting external components. I have just booted them up with a bench power supply (at 3.3V) loaded the same code that is running the project mentioned and measured the voltage on the 3 pins set to input with a pull-up namely Gpio12, 2 and 0. This is why I originally left off the schematic. As I am still baffled how a pin can have a higher voltage than the MCU input without any other voltage anywere near it.

Just as a side note the pins weirdly blow in a strong pull to 2,8V and are being read as LOW but this is outside the scope of the current question.

Comment: is the circuit feeding power into the pin?

Comment: What is attached to the switch?  Are your grounds all tied together?

Comment: This indeed sounds unhealthy, but no one is going to be able to help you until you provide documentation of your setup.

Comment: There is no higher voltage fed into the circuit during testing but have a 12V power source running in normal operation that is reduced and regulated to 3.3V. I was worried this was somehow "leaking" through to the pin so, during testing, I only fed the circuit directly with 3.3V. The switch pulls the pin to ground. The ground from the 3.3V source is used. Grounds are tied together, yes.

Comment: @CalvinMAnnandale - Hi, (a) Can you please edit the question & add (i) a full schematic, and (ii) some photos of the physical hardware? (b) You said: "*I have noticed this higher voltage on the other two pins I have running pull-ups as well*". The common factor would be the supply voltage to the IC. More details needed there, also a fuller explanation about the 12V power source you mentioned, how it is regulated to 3.3V, what you changed for testing and what difference it made to measured voltages (again, please edit the question to add them). (c) Do you have an oscilloscope to view voltages?

Comment: @SamGibson (a) please see attached schematic. Not sure if this will help though as there's very little help on that regarding the specific issue I'm facing but hopefully it helps trigger a thought. (b) The IC is running at a steady 3.3V and is not being supplied with a higher voltage whether being run by my 12V supply through the onboard voltage regulator or by 3.3V direct from my bench power supply. These were the two test cases, sorry for confusion. (c) Yes I have an oscilloscope

Comment: @CalvinMAnnandale - Hi, I have deleted my answer, because so much of my hypothesis was rendered obsolete by your new information e.g. corrections to the schematic and the new test results. I have copied that new information into the question from your comments on my answer, so other readers can still see and consider it. Although there are some tests that I would perform if I could, without me being able to do interactive measurements with your test case in my hands, I don't think I can add more value at this stage.

Comment: (cont'd) By the way, there seems to be a possible contradiction (or at least, lack of clarity) in part of your update. You said: "*the inductive loads could have an issue I do have external protection on both of those loads*" so there is (unspecified) protection, implying that the inductive loads *won't* be a problem. But then you said: "*the blown pins could have been caused by this*" which implies those inductive loads *might* be a problem. That left me confused about what you were trying to say. Did you mean to add a "not" somewhere? Anyway, good luck with your investigation!

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the edit to the question and for your efforts. I have changed it so the reader understands that the inductive loads have external protection. Any suggested tests I can carry out to help? Thanks again for your insights